# MS SQL Server equivalent of to_char

Tags: sql-server, datetime, string-formatting, amazon-redshift

In Redshift, we use below command for converting datetime to a formatted string as shown below-

```
to_char(<any datetime column>, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM') AS dateTime
```

How can I achieve the same in MS SQL server. I used convert and cast but I cannot exactly format it the same way as above. I used

```
select convert(varchar(20),<any datetime column>,9)
```

Comment: [`Format()`?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: but tag your SQL Server version, as that's a relatively recent addition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [**`format()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) in Sql Server 2012+:

```
select format(getdate(),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QWPWO57409

returns: `10/31/2017 06:33 PM`

---

Prior to SQL Server 2012, you can use a combination of [**`convert()`** styles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and some string manipulation to get something similar (without leading `0` on hours):

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)
  + stuff(right(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),100),8),7,0,' ')
```

returns: `10/31/2017  6:40 PM`

Comment: I love this new function!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
[Format (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)